# GetSelectedItem on OnItemClickListener (Android)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

let's say you have a listview with custom xml-objects on it in a row.
But you want to address specifically the textview, if it's press in the OnItemClickListener. What's the way - or bette - the best practise to do so? If i check in the OnItemClick method, the specifically element in the row (e.g. the textview, doesn't get recognized.

Comment: use custome listener interface and use it inside Holder.that way you can use specific item click listener

Comment: you will get views in Listview adapter. and you can use setOnClickListener in Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onClickListener to that textView in the getView method of your adapter like this.

```
viewHolder.myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"item= "+data.get(position).getTitle());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work create a class which extends **BaseAdapter** class and implements all its method

1.Now in the getView() method of this class initialize all the required views in a single item of listview

2.After that attach onClickListener() to the desired textView.

3.After that select your custom adapter class in the listView.setAdapter() method

This should help you if it doesn't work use **RecyclerView** instead and do all the above task in the **onCreateViewHolder()** method of **RecyclerView.adapter** Class

Answer (score 0):

```
if you have model class name **User** now you can get user info by using


 viewHolder.tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

          User user = data.get(pos);
          user.getTitle();


                Log.d(TAG,"item= "+data.get(position).getTitle());
            }
        });
```